# Docker Desktop - can i copy files to WSL docker-desktop or docker-desktop-data folders?

Tags: laravel, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop

My Laravel project is too slow on Windows Docker with WSL2. In other topics people say, that project files can be moved to WSL folder, so it will work faster. They are telling about some Ubuntu folder

But after Docker Desktop install I have only two folders: docker-desktop and docker-desktop-data

Should I install Ubuntu distro, to have Ubuntu folder, or I can copy my files to docker-desktop folder?

I move to WSL folder in Windows, but can see only docker-desktop and docker-desktop-data folders. Just a question, can I store project files in docker-desktop folder?

Comment: You have to go to the network tab on the windows file explorer and you will see _Linux_ (only available on windows 11), then you will see the distro itself. Always use WSL (linux path) instead of windows path from WSL